# How to bind object to Laminas form with multiple fieldsets using Doctrine Hydrator

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, laminas

How can I bind an object to a laminas form using Doctrine Hydrator?  The bind function populates the base fieldset, but will not populate my address fieldset which is a mapped entity in the user/member.

This is my form code that pulls in my field sets. All form fields are created in the view, but the bind method doesn't seem to be aware of my address fieldset.

```
namespace Member\Form;

use Doctrine\Laminas\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Laminas\Form\Element\Collection;
use Laminas\Form\Form;

class MemberProfileForm extends Form
{
    /**
     * __construct($objectManager)
     * @param \Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('member-profile-form');
        
        /**
         * Set the hydrator
         */
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager));
        
        /**
         * Set the user base fieldset
         */
        $profileFieldset = new \User\Form\ProfileFieldset($objectManager);
        $profileFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($profileFieldset);
        
        /**
         * Set the home address fieldset
         */
        $homeAddressFieldset = new \User\Fieldset\AddressFieldset($objectManager);
        $this->add($homeAddressFieldset);
        
        /**
         * Security & submit
         */
        $this->add([
            'name' => \Application\Fieldset\SubmitCsrfFieldset::FIELDSET_NAME,
            'type' => \Application\Fieldset\SubmitCsrfFieldset::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

The documentation demonstrates how to do a one to many scenario, but this is a one to one and nothing I try works, leaving the form field blank, though the profile form fields are populated from the base fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

I think your address fieldset should be inside your profile fieldset.

You should have an address property inside your profile entity which should map to your address entity. Doctrine object hydrator should pick this relationship up from your entites.